# My for loop is only executing it's statements once

Tags: java

Like the title says, my for loop statement is only executing once the test condition is proven false.

```
    public static int exponent(int a,int b)
    {
      int c = a;
      int count;
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      for(count = 1; count < b; count = count + 1, c = c * a);
      {
      System.out.println(count);

      }

    return c;
    }
```

From what I know, this for loop should display the value of variable "count" for each iteration of the loop, however it only ends up displaying the final value of variable "count".

Comment: semi colon after the loop closing brace...

Comment: Why is there a scanner here?

Comment: Forgot to delete the scanner, i was trying all sorts of whacky things to try and get it to work. Turns out it was just a semi-colon. *facepalm*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
public static int exponent(int a,int b)
{
  int c = a;
  int count;
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

  for(count = 1; count < b; count = count + 1, c = c * a)
  {
  System.out.println(count);

  }

return c;
}
```

That one semicolon after the for statement was not correct.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me so fast! Turns out I caught that right before I checked this page just now. I am loving Java but semi-colons have been the biggest headache givers iv'e had so far! I'm sure there is much more to come.

Comment: Glad I could help! Yeah it'll need some time to get adjusted to. Hope you're using a somewhat good IDE to program, because semicolon(&other syntax) errors were always super hard to catch by eye when I first started with Java.

Comment: Iv'e been using jGrasp, as it is the IDE we are using in the class I am in. Iv'e heard it isn't the best one to use, but as a beginner I don't know which one would best suit my needs. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd recommend the JetBrain tools in general. They have one for each popular language. For Java, this would be IntelliJ. You get the Pro version for free as a student.

Comment: I will give it a look! Thanks again!

Comment: Sure thing. If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as solved.

Comment: I once lost a day or so to a semicolon at the end of an if statement (on an embedded C system). Since then I always include braces (and put the opening one on the same line as the statement it belongs to).